# LM741 gives different result LM348

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I have put the following circuit together using a LM348 which is described as a Quad 741.

[image]

It works perfectly using a 0-5V source. It only requires 1 op-amp so I had a 741 kicking around and wired this in. The circuit is a ramp so if you apply 5v to vin it will ramp up based on the RC circuit, when turned off it will ramp to 0. With the 741 it only ramps down to around 1.8 V not 0. If I remove the op-amp from the circuit the inputs are 0v so the feature is within the op-amp.

The difference (apart from multiple op-amps) between the 348 and 741 is the offset adjustment pins. The voltage seems too large for this adjustment, I just have them floating in any case.

Why would the output not be 0v?

Comment: 5V is not enough power supply voltage for a 741 op amp.

Comment: The spec sheet for this exact chip (µA741) says 5-15v but if you can recommend a 8 pin single op-amp I am open to suggestions.

Comment: The 741 is only *guaranteed* to have outputs that are 3V or 4V away from the power rails (depending on version). There are numerous 8 pin devices that have superior output stage performance. Just go to any of the usual suspects and search for rail to rail out.

Comment: If you want to use the 741 as a single-supply opamp you must have at least 10 volts between the supply pins, which means that if you want supply minus to be GND, supply plus  must be >=10V. And, as @PeterSmith noted,  the output will never go to zero volts with GND = zero volts.

Comment: The 741 is **ancient** and not suited very well for a single 5 V supply for all the reasons listed above. You're far better of using a more modern opamp designed for a single 5 V supply, examples are: MCP601, MCP6001, TLC271 to name a few. These **are** capable of pulling their ouput to allmost 0 V.

Comment: @maxum The minimum recommended supply voltage for the 741 is +/-5V = 10v total. Details like that are actually quite important.

Comment: I grabbed another op amp and the voltage has dropped lower but not as low as I wanted. The only options I have locally are LM4558, NE5534n, NE5534AN, OPA2134PA, OP07C/D ,TL071/LF351, TL072/LF353, LM301 ,LM308, LM358
and MC1458. I have checked the datasheet of each and none mention rail-to-rail. what specific characteristic should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rail to rail op-amp was required for this circuit